# findAssoc in tm returns inconsistently

Tags: r, tm

findAssoc is supposed to return *"A named list. Each list component is named after a term in terms and contains a named numeric vector."*  Here's a simple example:

```
txt  <- c("alpha bravo", "alpha charlie", "alpha charlie", "zulu")
corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
dtm  <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
x    <- findAssocs(dtm, "alpha", .01)
print(x)
        alpha
charlie  0.58
bravo    0.33

str(x)
 num [1:2, 1] 0.58 0.33
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "charlie" "bravo"
  ..$ : chr "alpha"
```

Yet for some single matches, it returns a vector, and concatenates the words, separating with a period:

```
y <- findAssocs(dtm, "charlie", .01)
print(y)
charlie.alpha 
         0.58
str(y)
Named num 0.58
 - attr(*, "names")= chr "charlie.alpha"
```

This makes processing the results difficult; I can work around this, but is this expected behavior or a bug I should file with the maintainers?